# Problem with integrating keras into a sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I am using a wrapper from `sklearn` to find the best hyperparameters for my Keras model. Briefly, this model is a conv autoencoder and takes in data with the shape of (x,x,x). Keras wrapper seems to take data with the shape of (x,x). Since it is autoencoder model, the data would be in the shape of (x,x,x) and I think because of this reason, I am getting the following error `ValueError: Invalid shape for y: (3744, 288, 1)`. How can I resolve this?

full code

```
"""
# Load libraries
"""
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

# Set random seed
np.random.seed(0)

"""
## Load the data
"""

master_url_root = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/numenta/NAB/master/data/"

df_small_noise_url_suffix = "artificialNoAnomaly/art_daily_small_noise.csv"
df_small_noise_url = master_url_root + df_small_noise_url_suffix
df_small_noise = pd.read_csv(
    df_small_noise_url, parse_dates=True, index_col="timestamp"
)

df_daily_jumpsup_url_suffix = "artificialWithAnomaly/art_daily_jumpsup.csv"
df_daily_jumpsup_url = master_url_root + df_daily_jumpsup_url_suffix
df_daily_jumpsup = pd.read_csv(
    df_daily_jumpsup_url, parse_dates=True, index_col="timestamp"
)



"""
## Prepare training data
"""


# Normalize and save the mean and std we get,
# for normalizing test data.
training_mean = df_small_noise.mean()
training_std = df_small_noise.std()
df_training_value = (df_small_noise - training_mean) / training_std
print("Number of training samples:", len(df_training_value))

"""
### Create sequences
Create sequences combining `TIME_STEPS` contiguous data values from the
training data.
"""

TIME_STEPS = 288

# Generated training sequences for use in the model.
def create_sequences(values, time_steps=TIME_STEPS):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(values) - time_steps):
        output.append(values[i : (i + time_steps)])
    return np.stack(output)


x_train = create_sequences(df_training_value.values)
print("Training input shape: ", x_train.shape)

"""
## Build a model

We will build a convolutional reconstruction autoencoder model. The model will
take input of shape `(batch_size, sequence_length, num_features)` and return
output of the same shape. In this case, `sequence_length` is 288 and
`num_features` is 1.
"""

# Create function returning a compiled network
def create_network(optimizer='Adam'):
    model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            layers.Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])),
            layers.Conv1D(
                filters=32, kernel_size=7, padding="same", strides=2, activation="relu"
            ),
            layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
            layers.Conv1D(
                filters=16, kernel_size=7, padding="same", strides=2, activation="relu"
            ),
            layers.Conv1DTranspose(
                filters=16, kernel_size=7, padding="same", strides=2, activation="relu"
            ),
            layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
            layers.Conv1DTranspose(
                filters=32, kernel_size=7, padding="same", strides=2, activation="relu"
            ),
            layers.Conv1DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=7, padding="same"),
        ]
    )
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.optimizer(learning_rate=0.001), loss="mse", metrics=['mae'])

    return model

# Hyper-parameter tuning

# Wrap Keras model so it can be used by scikit-learn
CAE = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_network, verbose=0)

# Create hyperparameter space
epochs = [5, 10]
batches = [5, 10, 100]
optimizers = ['rmsprop', 'adam']

# Create hyperparameter options
hyperparameters = dict(optimizer=optimizers, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batches)

# Create grid search
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=CAE, cv=3, param_grid=hyperparameters)

# Fit grid search (we use train data as test data here since this is reconctruction model)
grid_result = grid.fit(x_train, x_train, validation_split=0.1)

# View hyperparameters of best neural network
print(grid_result.best_params_)
```

Comment: I changed 1 line to make the example working: return model # not return network;  also the way you pass `optimizer` choice is not correct - pls fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special problem with `KerasClassifier.fit()`. If you look at its source code, you'd see that it throws error if `y` has >2 dimensions. Perhaps it is not aimed at autoencoders optimization :)

Your choices are:

1. subclass `KerasClassifier.fit()` and fix this limitation
2. use another optimization engine (my preference would be `optuna`)
3. squeeze the extra dimension out in the end of the model and reduce dimensions in `y_train`.

for 3) use these lines:

```
layers.Reshape((288,))  # add in the end of model constructor

y_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[:-1])  # to match the above change 

grid_result = grid.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.1)  # feed y_train
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more, most elegant solution:
replace `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier` with `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor`. The latter is not checking dimensions of `y`.